# Memory size with creating image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I have a website that among other things creates an image based on values from a database.
The problem is that the image is over 40000 pixels high and just under 2000 pixels wide.

The image is saved after creating and then shown on the page.
I use jpg compression of 70% to reduce the file size a bit, but the problem is that if I run the website locally in my VS2010, the image is created, but when run on the server, the image has 0 bytes.

My guess is, that the server (IIS7) doesn't get enough memory to process it.
What can I do so the webserver can create this image?

Comment: Do you have any errors? If there's a memory problem, the web page will throw an exception. If you have no exception then it might be something else. An option could be to split the big image in 4.

Comment: At first there was an error, after I resized the image by removing the overkill on white space below the image, the error was gone, but the file to which the bitmap was saved, was 0 bytes.

Comment: Are you sure the white space removal code works properly?

Comment: it's not really white space removal. While drawing I keep track of the vertical position. Once the drawing is finished I resize the bitmap to a max of that vertical position + 10 pixels overhead.